# Artboard boundary not visible in Illustrator CC

Tags: adobe-illustrator, artboard

I have just started using Illustrator CC 2016, Im used to CS6 (with grey background and clearly defined artboards + boundary).

When I create a new document and create some artboards all I'm seeing is the transparency grid. When I hide transparency grid I still do not see the artboard bounding box. If I turn on video rulers they show the area, but still no defining black outline for the artboard.

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 4):

**View » Show Artboards** should do the trick! I am using an Apple computer, so my View menu shows up on top of the Illustrator window itself. Your computer may be a little different, but as long as you find that menu, you should be good to go!

[image: Top Menu » "View" » "Show Artboards"]